# If no value then remove space in email notification

Tags: kentico

Currently i am using one email notification for form where i have around twenty attendees.I used these value to show in email notification.Below is my code:

```html
{% AttendeeFirstName %} {% AttendeeLastName %}
{% AttendeeFirstName2 %} {% AttendeeLastName2 %}
{% AttendeeFirstName3 %} {% AttendeeLastName3 %}
{% AttendeeFirstName4 %} {% AttendeeLastName4 %}
{% AttendeeFirstName5 %} {% AttendeeLastName5 %}
{% AttendeeFirstName6 %} {% AttendeeLastName6 %}
{% AttendeeFirstName7 %} {% AttendeeLastName7 %}
{% AttendeeFirstName8 %} {% AttendeeLastName8 %}
{% AttendeeFirstName9 %} {% AttendeeLastName9 %}
{% AttendeeFirstName10 %} {% AttendeeLastName10 %}
{% AttendeeFirstName11 %} {% AttendeeLastName11 %}
{% AttendeeFirstName12 %} {% AttendeeLastName12 %}
{% AttendeeFirstName13 %} {% AttendeeLastName13 %}
{% AttendeeFirstName14 %} {% AttendeeLastName14 %}
{% AttendeeFirstName15 %} {% AttendeeLastName15 %}
{% AttendeeFirstName16 %} {% AttendeeLastName16 %}
{% AttendeeFirstName17 %} {% AttendeeLastName17 %}
{% AttendeeFirstName18 %} {% AttendeeLastName18 %}
{% AttendeeFirstName19 %} {% AttendeeLastName19 %}
```

In the above it is working fine if value is present any of the attendees, But here one issue is if user used some two attendees so two attendees is showing but for other 18 it is showing big blank space then after that whatever field used that is showing.
How can i remove this space if no value present for that attendees from email notification.

```html
   In the below code i used as for loop but not getting the value.

 {% size = GroupSize;attName="";j=0;for(i=0; i < size; i++){if(j==0){attName+=AttendeeFirstName+ " "+AttendeeLastName}else if(j>0){
    attName+=AttendeeFirstName+j+ " "+AttendeeLastName+j}j+=1;}; attName#%}
```

Below is the code used as suggested by rocky:

```html
Additional Attendees:
{% att1 = AttendeeFirstName + " " + AttendeeLastName; if(att1 != " ") { return att1; } else { return ""; } #%}
{% att2 = AttendeeFirstName1 + " " + AttendeeLastName1; if(att2 != " ") { return att2; } else { return ""; } #%}
{% att3 = AttendeeFirstName2 + " " + AttendeeLastName2; if(att3 != " ") { return att3; } else { return ""; } #%}
{% att4 = AttendeeFirstName3 + " " + AttendeeLastName3; if(att4 != " ") { return att4; } else { return ""; } #%}
```

In the above code if we use FirstName only then for others code there is some space in email notification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the big blank space is caused by the space between the brackets: `%} {%`

**Advice no. 1:** You don't have to use separate the code blocks.

```
{% AttendeeFirstName + " " + AttendeeLastName %}
```

**Advice no. 2:** Use conditions.

```
{% 
list = "";
br = "<br />";
att1 = AttendeeFirstName + " " + AttendeeLastName; if(att1 != " ") { list += att1+br; }  
att2 = AttendeeFirstName1 + " " + AttendeeLastName1; if(att2 != " ") { list += att2+br; }   
att3 = AttendeeFirstName2 + " " + AttendeeLastName2; if(att3 != " ") { list += att3+br; }  
att4 = AttendeeFirstName3 + " " + AttendeeLastName3; if(att4 != " ") { list += att4; }  
return list; #%}
```

**Advice no. 3:** Use loops. I don't know how you store your data but it'd be much cleaner to iterate through a collection instead of hard-coding all twenty attendees.

**Advice no. 4:** Have a look at the macro syntax documentation, especially [conditions](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/macro-expressions/macro-syntax#Macrosyntax-Conditionalstatements) and [loops](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/macro-expressions/macro-syntax#Macrosyntax-Iteration(loops)).

Comment: Hi rocky, as per your suggestion i put this in for loop but value is not coming. I edited my question with latest for loop.

Comment: The K# language (and most of other languages) doesn't work like this. The statement `AttendeeFirstName+j` will simply result in addition of values of `AttendeeFirstName` and `j`...So the output will be something like "Vikash1" or just "1" if `AttendeeFirstName` is empty. If you had a collection with attendees you'd usually do something like `Attendees[j].FirstName + " " + Attendees[j].LastName`... if you don't have a collection of objects available, use the approach no.2 from my answer.

Comment: I don't have a collection of objects available so i tried approach 2. For testing purpose i used four attendees in email content and i selected only one attendee in the form. when i checked the email content still there are space for other attendees. How can i remove this space.

Comment: Do you know what kind of whitespace it is? Is it a space, linebreak or tab? Could help us identify what's going on...

Comment: as i understood it is space of if condition code space. like some 4 or five if condition is used and 1 has validated and shown so for other if condition space is there.

Comment: Rocky i updated my question with used of approach 2. Please look for this in above.

Comment: see my updated answer...use whatever you need as a linebreak

Comment: Thanks rocky, Your solution worked for me. I am upvoting your answer.